# How to trigger an event on double-click with GenericDirCtrl in WxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I want to load a file on double-click with the wx.GenericDirCtrl widget in wxPython (version 3.0.2.0, Python 2.7).

In the documentation (https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.GenericDirCtrl.html) double-clicking should trigger a EVT_DIRCTRL_FILEACTIVATED event but this does not exist in my version of wx.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The available events,in wx.version: 3.0.2.0, appear to be:

```
wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED
wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED
wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK
```

So you will probably have to run with `right click` for your purposes